# How to remove all translations from Translation Workbench?

Tags: translation, language, translation-workbench

Is it possible to remove all label translations for a specific language in the Translation Workbench, just reset everything? Removing them manually one by one is not an option. I tried playing with import/export, but .stf import won't accept blank values. Only workaround is to upload translations that are identical to original values, but this only works as long the original value is not changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found an answer to this in the docs (**[Translation Files](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=translation_file_description.htm&type=0)**):

> Delete a translation by replacing the desired value in the TRANSLATION column in either section with a left and right angle bracket
>   pair (< >). When the Bilingual file is imported, the label reverts to its original value

Comment: A link to the doc would be nice, though this is a good find!

Comment: `------------------TRANSLATED-------------------`

`# KEY LABEL TRANSLATION OUT OF DATE`

`PicklistValue.Countries__e.Australia Australia <TE_Australien> -`

`PicklistValue.Countries__e.Austria Austria <TE_Österreich> -`

`PicklistValue.Countries__e.Belgium Belgium <TE_Belgien> -`



This imported translation as "<TE_Australien>"  instead of reverting to its original value.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Replace translated values with "<>" and then import file  , check below,

**KEY LABEL TRANSLATION DEPRECATED**
ButtonOrLink.OpportunityLineItem.FCM_ManageProducts Manage Produkt  <>  -
CustomField.FCM_Address__c.FCM_Account.FieldLabel   Kunden-Lieferanten  <>  -
CustomField.FCM_Address__c.FCM_AccountName.FieldLabel   Name    <>  -
CustomField.FCM_Address__c.FCM_City.FieldLabel  Stadt   <>  -
CustomField.FCM_Address__c.FCM_Country.FieldLabel   Land    <>  -
CustomField.FCM_Address__c.FCM_IsBillTo.FieldLabel  Gesetzesentwurf für <>  -
CustomField.FCM_Address__c.FCM_StateProvince.FieldLabel Region / Provinz    <>  -
CustomField.FCM_Address__c.FCM_Street.FieldLabel    Strasse <>  -
CustomField.FCM_Address__c.FCM_ZipPostalCode.FieldLabel Postleitzahl    <>  -

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. This seems very similar to the existing accepted answer, but you can always edit to add more information to it to differentiate it.